# How to connet to my database with pdo in php

Tags: php, pdo

I want to get all data from my database table 'user_info' with PDO in PHP.
My username is 'root' and the database is name 'meta'.

How to connect to it with PDO with PHP.

Comment: Please use a search engine in the future. https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php Also, don't use `root` for an application. Create a user with appropriate access levels and give it a password (also give your root user a password).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$adr = 'localhost';
$dbn = 'meta';
$usr = 'root';
$pwd = 'password';

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$adr;dbname=$dbn", $usr, $pwd);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM table;");
$stmt->execute();
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    // Handle the $row content
}
?>
```